# Optimizing a For loop in a Monte Carlo simulation

Tags: montecarlo

I'm working on a correlated multivariate simulation with the Nataf Transform. I developed a code in Python (Intermediate knowledge) to perform a Monte Carlo simulation but it takes a lot of time on my computer. Could anyone help me to optimize these lines:

```
# Exponential distribution (stats package)
loc_exp = 15.0
scale_exp = 139.21617 

# Gamma distribution (l-moments package)
loc_gam = 0.72698
scale_gam = 16.18526

for i in range(len(rho_z)):

# Generate standarn normal variates
    n = int(1e6)
    r = np.random.normal(0, 1, [n,2])
    ui = r[:,0]
    uj = r[:,1]
    xi = stats.expon.ppf(stats.norm.cdf(ui), loc_exp, scale_exp)
    xj = lmoments.quagam(stats.norm.cdf(rho_z[i]*ui + np.sqrt(1.0 - rho_z[i]**2)*uj), para = np.array((loc_gam, scale_gam)))
# evaluate rho_x
R = np.corrcoef(xi,xj)
rho_x[i] = R[0,1]
```

I am using stats and lmoments packages. Thanks

Comment: Try timing each part and rewrite it so you can vectorize the computations as much as possible. I would start by using pre-generated random values from a LUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think vectorization is not the problem here. 
If you have a machine with multiple cores I would use that capability by running the loop in parallel. Most Monte Carlo codes can be formulated as embarrassingly parallel problems such as yours. You could use for instance the joblib package as described here: https://blog.dominodatalab.com/simple-parallelization/

Also, please check the indent of your last two lines. I think they should belong to the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I’ll read the link you just shared as I️ do have a machine with multiple cores.